# Problem with python while installing dependencies

Tags: python, node.js, npm

I'm learning node.js and the tutorial im watching included a code but when I execute `npm install` on the project directory I get the following error:

```
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\work-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.EXE
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\work-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
```

Comment: For some reason you need Python 2, but you have Python 3 in your PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like python is not installed properly? While installing python there will be a checkbox like Add python 3.8 to PATH.
Check the regedit to check the path.

here version might differ

Comment: I have python installed but the 3.7, not 3.8, shall i upgrade it?

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it out

Comment: The problem remains, i checked the path and its ok. Reading the error seems like is a syntax error when trying to execute a command in python, do u know what could i do?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have python installed on your machine.

Go to command prompt and type

> python

if you get something like this:

```
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

If you don't get this, that means you don't have python installed on your machine.

You can also try commands like

> python3

But in the end, you should see a similar result that I provided above.

Another way to check if you have python installed try enter following command:

Mac/Linux

> which python

Windows

> where python

If you have python installed it will print you location where it's installed

Comment: I have python installed but the 3.7, not 3.8, shall i upgrade it?